# ¿Cómo se llama una palabra que ilustra en sí el concepto abstracto que plasma?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

"Palabra" es una palabra. "Esdrújula" es una esdrújula. "Polisílabo" es polisílabo. Y en Chile una "chuchada" es una [chuchada](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=chuchada).

¿Qué nombre recibe este tipo de palabra?

Pensé en "autodefinido", pero en realidad no son palabras que se "definen" a sí mismas, además que en algunos países así le dicen a los crucigramas.

Comment: Estoy tentado a responder con una única palabra "respuesta". ¿Qué es esto, diríais? Pues una... respuesta ;-)

Comment: Rodrigo, traté de captar en el título más precisamente lo que estás preguntando, pero si no quedó mejor, hazle un rollback por favor.

Comment: la palabra "palindroma" deberia cambiar a palindromordnilap

Comment: @Mike jajaja, eso sería algo "rimbombante".

Comment: Otras más: cacofónico, pronunciable y singular.

Comment: ¿Autorreferente? Al menos así se les dice a las frases que lo son.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El DRAE no lo recoge, lo que me hace sospechar, pero en la no tan fiable wikipedia tenemos:

> Una palabra es **autológica** si se describe a sí misma.
>
> Fuente: [Paradoja de Grelling-Nelson](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoja_de_Grelling-Nelson)

El artículo indica

> Por ejemplo "corto" y "esdrújula" son **autológicas**, ya que la palabra "corto" es relativamente corta y la palabra "esdrújula" es esdrújula. Las palabras que no son autológicas se denominan heterológicas. "Largo" es una palabra **heterológica**, al igual que "monosilábico".

Desafortunadamente los enlaces a "autológico" y "heterológico" enlazan al mismo artículo de wikipedia (Paradoja de Grelling-Nelson).

El DRAE contempla *[autólogo, ga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4TFpej7)*, pero no "autológico" y otras búsquedas que sigo haciendo no han podido, de momento, confirmar la validez de "autológico" y "heterológico".

Comment: 'La paradoja utiliza las palabras **inventadas** "autológico" y "heterológico"'

Comment: @rsanchez Cierto (y buen punto). La paradoja fue formulada en 1908. Si desde entonces "autológico" y "heterológico" no han pasado al diccionario o no han sido sustituidas por un término más apropiado, creo que podemos suponer que no existen tales términos en español. Habrá por tanto que contentarse con "autológico" y "heterológico", referenciando esta paradoja tal vez, para dar contexto.

Comment: sera Antonimo autologica o heterologica o una paradoja ?
pues antonimo es el antonimo de un sinonimo, pero antonimo no es un antonimo de si mismo, 
si antonimo es un antonimo de si mismo, terminaria siendo un sinonimo, 
pero puesto que el antonimo es un sinonimimo de antonimo, entonces tenemos una paradoja  ?

Comment: @Mike, jajaja sí es genial. En el enlace explica que esta paradoja (de Grelling-Nelson) puede convertirse en una paradoja "lógica" como la de Russell: "una palabra autológica se entiende como un conjunto, tal que uno de sus elementos es el mismo conjunto. La cuestión sobre si la palabra "heterológico" es heterológica" se convierte en la cuestión sobre si el conjunto de todos los conjuntos que no se contienen a sí mismos se contiene a sí mismo como un elemento." >>> A mi me acaba de entrar dolor de cabeza!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a comment by @Angus under the original question I propose *autorreferente*. This does not occur in the DLE but the Wikipedia page on [*autorreferencia*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorreferencia) does use it.

Another option would be [*recursivo*](https://dle.rae.es/recursivo?m=form) which does occur in the DLE.